# Search for repeated consecutive characters in strings and replace each string with 1 or 0

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, repeat, non-repetitive

I am having an array

```
$array = array("ab","aab","abb","abab","abaab","abbb");
```

I want to search the elements that contain duplicate consecutive characters like `aab`, `abb`, `abbb` and  replace them with `1`.

Conversely, if an element does not contain any duplicate consecutive characters, (like `ab` and `abab`) then it should be replaced with `0`.

Answer (score 1):

This approach uses array_map and preg_match to return an array of true/false matches based on a repeating string. The keys will match your input array.

`(.)` finds any character and puts it into the first capturing group, then `\1` makes sure the exact matching character follows it.

```
$array = array("ab","aab","abb","abab","abaab","abbb");
function StringHasRepetition( $string )
{
  return preg_match('/(.)\1/', $string);
}
$matches = array_map('StringHasRepetition',$array);
print_r( $matches );
// Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 )
```

---

As a Lambda function:

```
$array = array("ab","aab","abb","abab","abaab","abbb");
$matches = array_map( function( $string ){
  return preg_match('/(.)\1/', $string);
} ,$array);
print_r( $matches );
// Array ( [0] => 0 [1] => 1 [2] => 1 [3] => 0 [4] => 1 [5] => 1 )
```

Comment: I misunderstood the question at first.  Great answer +1.  Perfect regex pattern.  Tight.

Comment: Thanks, sometimes regex is the solution! :D

Comment: I just realized a cleaner way.  See my answer.  (I still like yours, so I am not removing the upvote.)

Answer (score 1):

`preg_replace()` can manipulate your entire array with just two regex patterns in a single call.  First convert strings with no consecutive repeated characters to `0`.  Then convert all non `0` values to `1`.

Code: ([See Demo Link for a more verbose breakdown of the method](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/1b0410410535738b1261f02f3047d905975c058d))

```
$array=["ab","aab","abb","abab","abaab","abbb",'1','11','10','0','00100','1101','01'];
var_export(preg_replace(['/^(?:(.)(?!\1))*$/','/^(?!0$).*/'],[0,1],$array));
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '0',
  1 => '1',
  2 => '1',
  3 => '0',
  4 => '1',
  5 => '1',
  6 => '0',
  7 => '1',
  8 => '0',
  9 => '0',
  10 => '1',
  11 => '1',
  12 => '0',
)
```